# Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (500)

Tags: google-chrome, application-cache

After listening the application cache error, sometimes, I randomly capture the error "Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (500) xxx.png" during loading application cache files. I can sure the file exits and most of error time, the error file is not the same one. If the error occurs, refreshing the page can solve it.

Does anyone know what the Application Cache 500 error code mean? Is it related with network?

I am using Chrome version 60+